# BIND - zone not loaded due to errors

Tags: bind

After upgrading from Ubuntu 8.04 to 10.04 my DNS isn't working properly anymore.

I keep getting this error when I run named-checkzone example.com /var/cache/bind/example.com.zone.db

```
zone example.com/IN: NS 'mx002a.example.com' has no address records (A or AAAA)
zone example.com/IN: not loaded due to errors.
```

in /var/cached/bind/example.com.db

```
$TTL 3D
@       IN      SOA     mx002a.example.com. chantra.example.com. (
                        200608081       ; serial, todays date + todays serial #
                        8H              ; refresh, seconds
                        2H              ; retry, seconds
                        4W              ; expire, seconds
                        1D )            ; minimum, seconds
;
;
mx002a.example.com IN A 192.168.85.19
example.com. IN NS mx002a.example.com.
mx001           60 IN A 192.168.85.17
mx001           60 IN A 192.168.85.18
```

Comment: I think you forgot the dot at the end of com before the address so mx002a.example.com. IN A 192.168.85.19 I also thought @ was origin and that is known from email address chantra or zone file that loaded this one so adding it seems redundant as it would be the default

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You must either specify the FQDN of everything in the zone file, or set $ORIGIN.  Also, if you specify an FQDN, you must specify it with a trailing dot (this is why it doesn't see your A record for mx002a.example.com).

To fix it:

```
$TTL 3D
$ORIGIN example.com.

@       IN      SOA     mx002a.example.com. chantra.example.com. (
                        200608081       ; serial, todays date + todays serial #
                        8H              ; refresh, seconds
                        2H              ; retry, seconds
                        4W              ; expire, seconds
                        1D )            ; minimum, seconds
;
;
@               IN NS mx002a.example.com.
mx002a          IN A 192.168.85.19
mx001           60 IN A 192.168.85.17
mx001           60 IN A 192.168.85.18
```

@ is a shortcut for just the origin.

Comment: That did the trick. It works. Thanks for your quick support!