# bind "can't find example: SERVFAIL"

Tags: domain-name-system, bind, dns-zone

I'm trying to setup a dns server on my LAN because my router doesn't support nat reflection and I have virtualhosts which require a domain (can't be reached by IP address) running on apache. I'm not very familiar with zone files but I think I'm on the right track. My domain is tenex.us and I want to reach it on my lan by using tenex.local (with an appropriate vhost added to apache). The dns server is working as it resolves and caches other addresses, including tenex.us but I get

> server can't find tenex.local: SERVFAIL

I have named.conf as follows

```
include "/etc/bind/named.conf.options";

include "/etc/bind/named.conf.local";
include "/etc/bind/named.conf.default-zones";

zone "tenex.local" IN {
  // this is the authoritative server for
  // tenex.us info
  type master;
  file "db.tenex";
};
```

and db.tenex as follows

```
$TTL 86400

@       IN      SOA     ns1.tenex.local.      craig.tenex.local. (
                        2014120705
                        28800          
                        7200           
                        864000          
                        86400          
                        )

                IN   NS      ns1    
                IN   NS      ns2    
@               IN   A  10.1.1.2
ns1             IN   A  10.1.1.2
ns2             IN   A  10.1.1.2
www             IN   CNAME @    
dev             IN   CNAME @
ftp             IN   CNAME @
```

and named.conf.options as follows (other files are default install files as of 12/6/14)

```
acl clients {
        10.1.1.0/24;
        10.1.2.0/24;
        localhost;
        localnets;
};

options {
        directory "/var/cache/bind";

        recursion yes;
        allow-query { clients; };

        forwarders {
                8.8.8.8;
                8.8.4.4;
        };
        forward only;

        dnssec-validation yes;

        auth-nxdomain no;    # conform to RFC1035
        listen-on-v6 { any; };
};
```

I'm not an expert on DNS but here is how I think this works. Correct me if I'm wrong, it will help me alot.

1. I query the server for tenex.local,
2. It sees that there is a zone listed for tenex.local and then returns the contents of the zone file for that entry to the device that queried it.
3. The device sees that the authoritive name server is ns1.tenex.local and that current address matches the address of ns1.tenex.local's A record in the zone file (10.1.1.2) so it is (supposed to) resolve to the A record for www.tenex.local/tenex.local/dev.tenex.local/etc.

Comment: Stop what you're doing. It is bad practice to use .local for anything. Instead you should use a subdomain of your actual domain for your internal network, or use your actual domain and split horizon DNS (views in BIND).

Comment: It was not working before the name change.

Comment: Bind skips the entire zone file if there's an error on any line and logs an error to say why but then finishes starting up and loading any other zone files. Check your error logs.  I suspect your CNAME entries are the problem.

Comment: I'd suggest using the hosts file on your local system to point to the LAN address of your website and then you can use the actual live domain of your site.  Google 'hosts file' for your client OS, assuming you're the only user that needs this LAN access, it will save you a ton of time compared to running a DNS server!

Answer (score 1):

I believe in order to write just `ns1 IN A ...` instead of `ns1.tenex.local. IN A ...`
you have to define `$ORIGIN tenex.local.` in your zone file. The same should apply for the `@` symbol.

See also [BIND - zone not loaded due to errors](https://serverfault.com/questions/438785/bind-zone-not-loaded-due-to-errors)

Comment: due the age, i suggests that it needs more details and clarity